# Finding domain of $f\colon x\mapsto\sin^{-1}\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$

Tags: functions

Consider $$\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$$ Dividing by $x\neq 0$, I get $$\dfrac{\frac{1}{x} + x}{2}\;$$ Now $$\left|\frac{\frac 1x + x}2\right|\geqslant 2$$ 
So, using this in original function, it's producing a range where $\sin^{-1}$ is not defined.

So the domain should be $\emptyset$. 
But my textbook says it's the set of real numbers. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $$ \frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\frac2{\frac{1}{x} + x}\ne\frac{\frac{1}{x} + x}{2}$$

Comment: @Did Err there was a typo..sorry

Comment: Are you really sure the question isn't about $x\mapsto\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$?

Comment: @PhilippeMalot yeah it is just opposite of argument you have written'

Comment: @J.Deff Friendly suggestion: check carefully your book. If it asks about the arcsine of $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, then see my comment. If it asks about the arcsine of $\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$, then it has a typo. (As an aside, I wonder what could be the meaning of the upvote of your "typo" comment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for $f(x)=\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

You have to solve
$$
\left|\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right|\le 1
$$
that can be written
$$
2|x|\le1+|x|^2
$$
that is
$$
(|x|-1)^2\ge0
$$
which is satisfied for every $x$.

### Answer for $f(x)=\arcsin\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$

You have to solve
$$
\left|\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right|\le 1
$$
that becomes
$$
1+|x|^2\le2|x|
$$
that is,
$$
(|x|-1)^2\le0
$$
that has, as solutions, $x\in\{1,-1\}$.

### Where are you going wrong?

The identity
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{2x}=\frac{\dfrac{1}{x\vphantom{y}}+x}{2}
$$
is of course valid.

For $x>0$, AM-GM gives
$$
\frac{\dfrac{1}{x\vphantom{y}}+x}{2}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}x}=1
$$
with equality for $x=\frac{1}{x}$, so for $x=1$.

There's no need to check the case $x<0$, because
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{2x}=-\frac{1+(-x)^2}{2(-x)}
$$
Thus clearly, for $x<0$,
$$
\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\le -1
$$
with equality for $x=-1$.

Comment: i have edited question.

Comment: Can you please let me know where i am wrong in my attempt. Thanks

Comment: @J.Deff You applied wrongly AM-GM

Comment: But arc sin only takes values between -1 and 1

Comment: @J.Deff No, it *accepts* value between $-1$ and $1$ and *returns* values between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. The expression $\arcsin t$ is only defined if $-1\le t\le1$.

Answer (score 2):

Try  using the basic property of sin inverse function
sin inverse cannot take value apart from the interval $[-1,1]$.

So, $-1\leq \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\leq 1$.

Solve the inequalities. u will get a set of values for the domain.
u r a little wrong in your inequality.
$\dfrac{x+1}{x}\geq 2$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$.

Therefore $\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{x+1}{x}}\leq 1$ for all x belongs to $(0,\infty)$. 
same we can check for negative x too.
The domain will be all real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see easily that $\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$ is always greater than $1$ or smaller that $-1$ (*in fact taking the derivative you have $x^2-1=0$ and $1$ gives a minimun and $-1$ gives a maximun*).

It follows that for all value of $x\notin\{-1,1\}$ the function
$$f\colon x\mapsto\sin^{-1}\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$$ is not defined, thus the domain of $f$ is the set $\{-1,1\}$ of just two points. There are maybe a typo in your book, in particular for $f=\sin$ instead of $f=\sin^{-1}$ all change.